# How to close the strange blank white panel on my screen?

Tags: window-manager, ui

It's really strange there is often a small white panel on my screen, which can be moved and resized, but I can find no way to close it.

I don't know where it is coming from. Does anyone know what's it and how to close it?

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the stickies application. Maybe you have that open? Can you type in the window?

Comment: Cmd+Q doesn't work ?

Comment: @KevinGrabher Should not be the stickies app, can't type anything

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Doesn't work, only restart can make it disappeared

Comment: Does it reappear randomly or after reboot?

Comment: @Kevin Randomly, sometimes it won't appear for a long time, but sometimes it just appeared, not sure what triggers it

Comment: Finally, I found it a temp panel for Chinese input method. There was maybe something wrong with one of Chinese input methods I used, this temp panel can't close itself